# Animating a Polyline in Google Maps Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-animation

I am searching for a way to implement this and So far I have reached nowhere. The Exact thing that I meant by animating a polyline is an uber-like animation. Things I have thought of is building each coordinate of routes using a loop and a timer. But it rather seems to be expensive, another thought is just to plot a simple curved line using canvas from one point to another (also hypothetical). In Android, it is achieved by using overlays, and flutter only supports tile overlays.

[image]

Comment: check [polylines](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMap/polylines.html) - your job is to pass a subset of the whole route inside some `AnimatedBuilder` / `ValueListenableBuilder` or similar widget

Comment: @pskink thankyou, So I should keep on passing subsets or I should add elements in the set?

Comment: you should pass a list of latlngs that form a route from A to B - at the begining it is just A, in the middle of animation it is a list from A to somewhere in between from A to B and finally in the end of animation it is the whole route from A to B, this can be useful: https://pub.dev/documentation/maps_toolkit/latest/maps_toolkit/SphericalUtil-class.html

Comment: @KrishBhanushali were you able to achieve this?

Comment: is this possible in react native?